# Taking first uppercase character of a multiple splitted string

Tags: java, string

So I want to print out the first uppercase character when splitting my String when it reaches a special character.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    if(input.contains("-")){
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
            String[] parts = input.split("-",2);
            String string1 = parts[0];
            String string2 = parts[1];
            System.out.print(string1.substring(0, 0) + string2.substring(0,0));

        }
    }
}
```

``

> I'll give an example of what I'd like it to do.

```
> input: Please-WooRk-siR
> output: PW
> input: This-Is-A-Test
> output: TIAT
```

So only print the first uppercase character of each substring.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your problem states "first capital letter", but in your example, you don't include the R in 'siR'. Do you mean the first letter, but only if it is capitalized?

Comment: Just the first uppercase character of each splitted substring.
I don't include R as it's not the first character of the substring.
I.E.
"Please-WooRk-siR" should become 3 seperate strings "Please","WooRk","siR". Where I only would like the first uppercase of each new string, iff. it's starting with an uppercase character. 
Hope that clears things up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

```java
      String str = "This-Is-a-Test-of-The-Problem";
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (String s : str.split("-")) {
         char c = s.charAt(0);
         if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            sb.append(c);
         }
      }
      System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Can you update your code to use StringBuilder? I want to up-click your answer but this is disturbing me

Comment: @ControlAltDel, unless this is a proven bottleneck in the code (unlikely), you're probably wasting time optimizing it.

Comment: By the compiler, string appending is also turned into a stringbuilder variant. So IMO it only makes code more confusing.

Comment: @n247s The Java compiler at least at the time of [this article in 2016](https://niels.nu/blog/2016/stringbuilder.html) doesn't help when you're concatenating within a loop. But I agree with you, don't make the code uglier for optimization. Do the optimization on the system as a whole, not every part.

Comment: @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ I am promoting good code practices, as an unknown number of people may at some point see this question and answer.

Comment: @ᴇʟᴇvᴀтᴇ Just another way of saying my thoughts on this. I think demonstrating this with StringBuilder is a good for showing those unfamiliar with the class what StringBuilder is for. I get your point, and I wouldn't necessarily care about this in my own code. But my thoughts are different in the case of a programming solution that many others may find.

Answer (score 3):

If you use regular expressions, you can use a zero-width negative lookahead to remove all characters that aren't capitals at the starts of words:

```
public static String capitalFirstLetters(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("(?!\\b[A-Z]).", "");
}
```

When you run the test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(capitalFirstLetters("Please-WooRk-siR"));
    System.out.println(capitalFirstLetters("This-Is-A-Test"));
}
```

It prints:

> PW
>   
> TIAT

Answer (score 1):

Update the code to this :

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        if (input.contains("-")) {
            String[] parts = input.split("-");
            for (String part: parts) {
                System.out.print(Character.isUpperCase(part.charAt(0)) ? part.charAt(0) : "");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Output :

1.

```
Input : A-Ba

AB
```

2.

```
Input : A-aB

A
```

3.

```
Input : A
```

Now, your test case :

```
Input : This-Is-A-Test

TIAT
```

Comment: @Robert can you try my answer ?

Comment: Thank you. This worked :) But for me personally the code is a little more complex for my liking. I'm not too sure the meaning behind "? part.charAt(0) : "" " at the end of your print

Comment: I already tried to upvote it, but it's not recorded since I've only now created this account. Too low reputation at the moment. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution by utilizing javas streaming API

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    if (input.contains("-")) {
        List<String> collect =
                Stream.of(input.split("-")) // get a stream of words
                .map(word -> word.substring(0, 1)) // get first character only
                .filter(character -> character.toUpperCase().equals(character)) // only keep if character is uppercase
                .peek(System.out::print) // print out character
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // just needed for stream to start
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using peek (which is for debugging only), remove that and the `.collect` and replace with `.forEach(System.out::print);`  And then you don't need to assign to a `List` either.